# UWP XAML - Create equally wide TextBlocks

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, uwp

I've got a list of student objects which is displayed like this:

[ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ8jl.png)

I want there to be spaces between the names and the number, but how can I realize that?

The XAML Code:

> ```
> <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" >
>
>     <ListView x:Name="StudentsList" ItemsSource="{Binding Studenten}">
>
>
>         <ListView.ItemTemplate>
>
>             <DataTemplate>
>                 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
>                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nachname}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
>                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Vorname}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
>                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding MatrikelNr}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
>                 </StackPanel>
>             </DataTemplate>
>         </ListView.ItemTemplate>
>     </ListView>
> </Grid> </Page>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Margin.

```
Margin = "Left,Up,Right,Down"
```

Or you can use one value for all directions

```
Margin = "Value"
```

So, your XAML should be something like this:

```
    <ListView x:Name="StudentsList" ItemsSource="{Binding Studenten}">


        <ListView.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nachname}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Vorname}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MatrikelNr}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid> </Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're after a fixed space after each name (say... 10pixels) then you can use the answer given by Kinani and just add a margin (let's say `Margin="10,0,0,0"`) to your 3rd TextBlock with the number binding in it.

If you'd like the number to be aligned over to the right to give the list an easier to read column-like feeling to it, you can do this:

```
<Grid Orientation="Horizontal">
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto">
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto">
          <ColumnDefinition>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nachname}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
     <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Vorname}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
     <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding MatrikelNr}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

Which will result in a look similar to this:

FirstName  SecondName          123456789

FName SName                         012345678